# How to overcome dependency issues while upgrading Python Requests Module on Amazon Linux Instance (EC2)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I have a simple Flask app which I try to run on my new AWS EC2 instance like this:

```
FLASK_APP=app.py flask run
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/my-folder/my-app/my-script.py", line 16, in <module>
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'disable_warnings'
```

One of the recommendations I found online is to upgrade my Python Requests module version. 
My current version is 1.2.3.

Here is what happens when I try upgrading it:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx my-folder]$ pip install requests --upgrade
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/e0/accfc1b56b57e9750eba272e24c4dddeac86852c2bebd1236674d7887e8a/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires argparse, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires cheetah, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires oauth, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires PrettyTable, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires pyserial, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: chardet, idna, certifi, urllib3, requests
  Found existing installation: chardet 2.0.1
Cannot uninstall 'chardet'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

How would you recommend to do the upgrade? 
Please also let me know if there is a better fix for the urllib3 issue.

Comment: Why aren't you using a virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is clashing with distro installation of chardet package you should use virtualenv as suggested by @joseph or you need to remove or update the chardet package using your package manager command in your case you are using amazon linux so you have to use following commands to remove chardet package manually

```
yum remove python-chardet
```